# Fedora 14 Xen virtual machine does not detect network

Tags: fedora, centos, xen

I'm trying to create a para-virt Fedora 14 Xen vm on a host running CentOS 5.5. The VM appears to initially install correctly (the installer finds `eth0` and can access the installation media). But when I restart the VM after the installation is completed the VM no longer sees any network, only lo. The VM does have one network connection according to virt-manager.

The host is running CentOS 5.5 64bit - completely up-to-date
The VM I am tring to install is F14 64bit (installing only the minimal group)

Update: After taking a look at this again, I think the problem has to do with my network setup. In the server I have two NICs (eth0, eth1) that I've bonded together (bond0). I'm guessing that I need to make changes to xen so it recognizes the bonded NICs, though I don't know why the guest gets a network interface during installation.

Comment: I`ve got a working setup with SLES10 servers and bonding. I did use the bond-device as "uplink" for a bridge and attach the DomUs to that bridge. No problem at all.